# Get a total value from an array containing both strings ('A','J'...) and numbers (deck of cards in an array)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an issue where I have an array containing a deck of cards (['A', 2,3,...'J',...])
I want to be able to pick a number of random cards and then get the total sum of them. for example J,4 should give me the total value of 14.

my current problem is that I can't figure out how to change the strings in the array to a number and
then add those together to get the total sum.

my current code is:

````
blackjackGame={
  'you': 0,
  'cards': ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'],
  'cardsMap' : {'A':1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8, '9':9, '10':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10},
}

let playerCards = 2
let card = [];
const YOU = blackjackGame['you']

// gives me a random card
function randomCard (){
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()* 13)
  return blackjackGame['cards'][rand];
}

// gives me the two starting cards for the player in an array so I can later add more 
function start(){
      for(let i= 0; i < playerCards; i++){
        card.push(randomCard())
      }
      
      return card
}

function totalValue (player){
 // this is where i have no idea what to do

  // let player = card.reduce(function (a,b){
  //   return a +b
  // }, 0)
  //  return player += blackjackGame['cardsMap'][card[0]]
}

console.log(start()) 
console.log(showScore(YOU)) ```

PS. I'm trying to create a blackjack game.
````

Answer (score 1):

Your `reduce` code is fine. Just add the reference to `blackjackGame.cardsMap` to retrieve the value that corresponds to card `b`.

```
let sum = card.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + blackjackGame.cardsMap[b];
}, 0);
```

Note that you cannot return that value via the argument of the function. Instead let the function *return* it with a `return` statement:

```
return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to map the face to the value. This will work:

```
function getValueOfCard( face ) {
    var cardOrder =" A234567891JQK";
    var faceStart = (""+face).substring(0,1);

    return Math.min(10, cardOrder.indexOf(faceStart)) 
}
```

If you want to get the values of all your cards, simply iterate over them (faster than reduce, and more easy to read).

Your card only needs the face and color, the other values follow.

```
card = { color: "spades", face : "King" };
getValueOfCard( card.face );

function totalValue ( playerHand ){
    // assuming an array of cards is the player hand
    var total = 0;
    for ( var card in playerHand ) {
        total += getValueOfCard( card.face );
    }
    return total;
}
```

I also recommend, that you create all your cards in one go, and then shuffle them, by picking two random numbers and switching these two cards. Do this in a loop for a couple of times, and you have a randomized stack of cards, which means you can actually treat it as a stack.

```
cardColors = ["♠","♥","♦","♣"];
cardFaces = ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'];

// create deck of cards
var stackOfCards = [];
for ( var a = 0; a < cardColors.length; a++ ) {
    var curColor = cardColors[a];
    for ( var i = 0; i < cardFaces.length; i++) {
        var curFace = cardFaces[i];
        card = { color : curColor, face : curFace };
        stackOfCards.push(card);
    }
}
// shuffle the deck
// then you can pop cards from the stack to deal...
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const blackjackGame={
  'you': 0,
  'cards': ['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
}

let playerCards = 2
let card = [];
const YOU = blackjackGame['you']

function getCardValue(card) {
   const v = blackjackGame['cards']
   if(v.indexOf(card) === -1){
       throw Error("not found")
   }
   
   // for each card above index 9 (10), always return 10
   return v.indexOf(card) > 9 ? 10 : v.indexOf(card) + 1
}

function randomCard (){
  let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()* 13)
  return blackjackGame['cards'][rand];
}

function deal(){
      for(let i= 0; i < playerCards; i++){
        card.push(randomCard())
      }
      
      return card
}


function calculateValue (cards){
  return cards.reduce(function (total, num){
    return total + getCardValue(num)
  }, 0)
}

document.getElementById('deal').addEventListener('click',(e) => {
   const cards = deal()
   console.log(cards)
   const playerValue = calculateValue(cards)
   YOU = playerValue
   console.log(playerValue)
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button id="deal">Deal</button>
<span id=cards />
<span id=total />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function start () {
  for (let i = 0; i < playerCards; i++) {
    cards.push(randomCard())
  }
  totalValue(cards)
}

function totalValue (cards) {
  cards.forEach((card) => {
    blackjackGame.you += blackjackGame.cardsMap[card]
  })
}

start()
console.log(blackjackGame.you)
```

You were on the right track with having a map. You can access objects with a variable by using someObj[yourVar]